# Can't get Keras Code Example #1 to work with multi-label dataset

Tags: keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

Apologies in advance.
I am attempting to recreate this CNN (from the Keras Code Examples), with another dataset.
https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/

The dataset I am using is one for retinal scans, and classifies images on a scale from 0-4. So, it's a multi-label image classification.

The Keras example used is binary classification (cats v dogs), though I would have hoped it wouldn't make much difference (maybe this is a big assumption on my part).

I skipped the 'image augmentation' part of the walkthrough. So, I have not created the

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    ]
)
```

part. So, instead of:

```
def make_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Image augmentation block
    x = data_augmentation(inputs)

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(x)
.......
```

at the beginning of the model, I have:

```
def make_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Image augmentation block
    x = keras.Sequential(inputs)

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(x)
.......
```

However I keep getting different errors no matter how much I try to change things around, such as `"TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement __len__."`, or `"ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "rescaling_3" (type Rescaling)."`.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you doing x = keras.Sequential(inputs)? This makes no sense.

Comment: Because the original code has `x = data_augmentation(inputs)`, where 
`data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    ]
)`. I don't have a need to augment the data, so this becomes:
`data_augmentation = keras.Sequential()`. And so if `data_augmentation` is simply calling on `keras.Sequential()`, hence `x = keras.Sequential(inputs)`... no?

Comment: No, if you do not need that, the identity operation would be x = inputs, not using Sequential.